# Check if 2 lines cut by 4 points

Tags: line, point

I have a class of point which has X and Y and a class of Line which has 2 points in it.

I want to check if 2 lines cut, how can I do that ?

Comment: Check [solving two linear equation in program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063322/solving-two-linear-equation-in-program/19073359#19073359)

Comment: Are your points integer or floating point?  (Subtle variation in best answer.)

Comment: what did you try so far? to me it seems like uni homework which you don't feel like doing.